# JavaScript click event bug (probably)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, event-handling, jquery-events

Got an annoying bug and have no idea what the problem is:

I hold global variable: `var cur_id=0;`
When I click on textarea I want to save textarea's id value to `cur_id`:

```
$('textarea.line').click(function  () {
    cur_id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Now I want set `cur_id` to zero in case you click anywhere but not in `content-append` class element:

```
 $(document).on('click touchstart', function(event) { 
    var el = $(event.target);
    if (!el.hasClass('content-append')) {
        cur_id = 0;  
    };
});
```

Also, there is an action which removes the textarea I just clicked:

```
$('.main-remover').click(function () {
    if (cur_id==0) {alert('Click a textarea to remove it!');} 
            else {document.getElementById(cur_id).remove();
        cur_id = 0;}
});
```

When I click textarea and then click any place in document `cur_id` becomes zero. That's OK, but when I click textarea and then click this button:

```
<button type="button" class="content-append main-remover btn btn-default">Remove</button>
```

I get 'Click a textarea to remove it!' message, which should be shown only if `cur_id==0` and it doesn't remove anything.
I think that somehow I'm wrong in this part:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function(event) { 
        var el = $(event.target);
        if (!el.hasClass('content-append')) {
            cur_id = 0;  
        };
    });
```

Please, help me to figure out what's wrong!

Comment: It seems to me like clicking your textarea triggers both your id-setting code and your id-clearing code. In that case, you can either a) give your textarea the content-append class; b) check in the document click handler that the target isn't a textarea before clearing cur_id; c) use something like event.stopPropagation() on the event object passed to your textarea callback.

Comment: first tip (a) works for me! Thank You so much!!!!!